# Two different results using console.log and return

Tags: javascript

I've been playing with chapter 3, *Parameters and Scopes* of **Eloquent Javascript** and I understand the difference between `console.log` and `return` but what I don't understand is why the developer tools console gives me two different results: `inside f1` and `"inside f1"`

```js
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
  console.log(x);
};
f1(); // inside f1
```

```js
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
  return x;
};
f1(); // "inside f1"
```

Comment: `console.log` is for print data

Comment: `console.log()` prints the value to the console, while `return` returns the value to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` and `return` do entirely different things.

`console.log` takes a value and shows it on the console. `return` stops a function running and (optionally) sends a value back to the calling context. `console.log` does not exit the function.

Let's explore both options.

```
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
  console.log(x);
};
f1(); // inside f1
```

Here, `console.log` simply outputs the value of `x` to the console. This involves no formatting and no other modification. The function `f1` does not return anything at all (there is an implicit `return;` at the end of the function).

Now let's look at the other bit of code:

```
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
  return x;
};
f1(); // "inside f1"
```

Here, the function `f1` has a return value, because you used the `return` statement. So `f1` returns a string `inside f1`. **Because you are calling `f1` from the console**, the console outputs the return value of the function to the console. If other code called `f1` (e.g. elsewhere in your application) there would be no output on the console.

The reason it is in `""` quotation marks is that the console, for reasons known only to the developers, opts to show string values in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet you are printed "inside f1" when you called console.log(x). In the second one you are just returning the x value.

To help you to understand what is happening just put the line below at the end of your second snippet:

```
console.log(f1());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing the same thing in the two snippets.

Check the screenshot.

In the first call (`f1()`) you see the output of the call to `log`, and then the returned value of the function, which is undefined since you return nothing.

In the secon call (`f2()`) you only see the returned value of the function, which returns a string.

[image: console screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet ,x has the scope of inner function so the value is "inside f1"

```js
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
  console.log(x);
};
f1();
```

where as in this snippet

```js
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
 return x;
};
console.log(x);
```

x has lost the inner scope now it has the scope of global x ,so thats the reason value is outside

If you still want to have the value of inner function x,as your returning x all you need to do is var result=f1();now the result would be inside f1

```js
var x = "outside";
var f1 = function() {
  var x = "inside f1";
  return x;
};
var result=f1();

console.log(result);
```